# i want to add a statement in blade @foreach loop

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I am new in **Laravel** and I  want to add "**,**" and "**and**" statement in between these two outputs, depending on how many speakers there is. But when I add this statement it loops.

So the "**and**" statement should go before the last. And I want to point out that it outputs first name separately than the last name.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h3>

  @foreach($lecture->speakers as $speaker)
  <b>{{$speaker->first_name}}{{$speaker->last_name}}</b>
  @endforeach

 </h3>                    
<div>
```

Would be grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($lecture->speakers); $i++)
    <b>{{ $lecture->$speakers[$i]->first_name}}{{ $lecture->$speakers[$i]->last_name}}</b>
    @if ($i < (count($lecture->speakers) - 2))
        and
    @elseif ($i === (count($lecture->speakers) - 2))
        ,
    @endif
@endfor
```

Well, I hope you got the idea, play with this code and I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div clas

    s="col-md-6">
                          <h3>
                        @for ($i = 0; $i < count($lecture->speakers); $i++)
                        <b>{{ $lecture->speakers[$i]->first_name}} {{ $lecture->speakers[$i]->last_name}}</b>
                        @if ($i < (count($lecture->speakers) - 2))
                        <b>,</b>
                        @elseif ($i === (count($lecture->speakers) - 2))
                        <b>and</b>
                        @endif
                        @endfor


                         </h3>

                          <div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help! Thats the logic I wanted to use but didnt define the variables correctly. This is the code that fitted perfectly.